# Sending a group the same message and get individual replies

Tags: sms, contact-groups

First, I'm an android rookie.  I'm managing a softball team.  I need to be able to send 40+ phones the same message at the same time (SMS is fine), but get individual replies (each player/parent's reply should come to me but not go to the whole team).  I just switched from an iPhone 4 to a Galaxy S5.  iPhone app "Group Text!" was perfect - I'm having trouble finding something comparable for the S5/android. Advice?

Comment: I'm sure there's a ton. Samsung may even have included something (they tend to load up their devices with...extras). Did you try searching in the Play Store? Did you look at the questions in the "Related" section to the right?

Comment: As far as I know, the builtin SMS app doesn't work with groups, meaning you'll get individual replies instead of group replies. Usually the problem when moving from iPhone to Android is the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp broadcast list may help you, i'm not %100 percent sure but it says "you should use broadcast lists to message multiple people at once." and as long as it is not group the others dont see the individual replies (i think)

Answer (score 0):

I used GO SMS Pro with previous android.   Has an ad at the top of each screen unless paid for.  Good functionality.